# Accessing Event Log from application registered in GAC

Tags: c#, .net, gac, event-log

I've .dll which is registered and executed from Global Assembly Cache. When I try to access Event Log

> EventLog.SourceExists("source name")

I'm getting an error:

> The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security.

Is there a way to avoid this error?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity of the application trying to access the Event Log does not have rights to read the Security log. By default, members of the `Administrators` group have this right. Your best option would be to grant said rights to the identity (or a group that this identity belongs to that should all have this right) in question. [Here's an article on that](http://blogs.technet.com/b/janelewis/archive/2010/04/30/giving-non-administrators-permission-to-read-event-logs-windows-2003-and-windows-2008.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing 2 security systems - Windows and .Net. GAC is purely .Net concept, but you are facing Windows permisssion restrictions on accessing event logs. Running application as administrator will allow access, also it may not be acceptable in your case.